# Htaccess ReWrite URL with ? in duplicate URL's

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-status-code-301

We have moved from IIS to Apache and used the below rewrite rule to redirect www.example.co.uk/Default.aspx?pagename=About-Us to the new page url www.example.co.uk/About-Us/

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/Default\.aspx$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pagename=About-Us$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  http://www.domain.co.uk/About-Us/ [R=301,L]
```

The problem is this rule is showing up as duplicate content in google WMT and the page is being served at both URL's...

Can anyone spot what is wrong with this rule?

Answer (score 0):

Change your rule to this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pagename=About-Us$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^Default\.aspx$  http://www.domain.co.uk/About-Us/? [R=301,L,NC]
```

Also note that it will take some time for search bots to remove duplicate URIs.

Comment: What does the ? do on the end - Thanks.

Comment: It removes original query string from target URI.